# Reload a DLL which has been imported with DllImport

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

My C# application (.NET Framework 4.0) imports an external unmanaged DLL with the following code:

```
[DllImport("myDLL.dll"), EntryPoint="GetLastErrorText"]
private static extern IntPtr GetLastErrorText();
```

Unfortunately there seems to be a bug in the third-party DLL. As a workaround I would need to unload the DLL and reload it afterwards. How can I do this? I've seen several posts but they all talk about managed DLLs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a wrapper around the library that manages the access to it. Then you can use native methods to call the library. Take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jonathanswift/archive/2006/10/03/dynamically-calling-an-unmanaged-dll-from-.net-_2800_c_23002900_.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll need to go down to using LoadLibrary/FreeLibrary/GetProcAddress as shown in [Difference between dllimport and getProcAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242331/difference-between-dllimport-and-getprocaddress) : Abbreviated sample (no error handling) below:

```
   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   private delegate Bool BarType(Byte arg); 
   ...
   IntPtr pDll= LoadLibrary("foo.dll");
   IntPtr pfunc = GetProcAddress(pDll, "bar");
   BarType bar = (BarType)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pFunc, typeof(BarType));
   var ok = bar(arg);
   FreeLibrary(pDll);
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `DllImport` to import the DLL, you could try using `LoadModule` (from WinAPI) to do so, and then use `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary` to do what you need as far as calling functions in it and unloading/reloading it.

[See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Might be a bit prettier/manageable if you used C++/CLR to glue C# and the unmanaged DLL together.